# MySQL CREATE TRIGGER IF variable is greater than set value error 1064

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I have been searching this site and Google for over an hour trying to figure out why I get this message:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '@msg = 'HIGH VALUE CUSTOMER - SALES GREATER THAN
>   $10K' IF (SALES > 10000) THEN' at line 5

...when running the SQL to create this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TOP_CUSTOMERS
AFTER INSERT ON ORDERS
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE msg VARCHAR(100)
    @msg = 'HIGH VALUE CUSTOMER - SALES GREATER THAN $10K'
IF (SALES > 10000) THEN
    SET CUSTOMERNOTES = @msg 
ENDIF
```

This is for an assignment that is due by midnight tomorrow night and I'm stumped because everything I have tried is in the same syntax as the examples and I'm not trying to create a complicated trigger.  Please help!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

This query has so many errors, syntax, variable define, delimiter etc... Even the inner logic is not clear as well, you should read about [**CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) first, here I only fix some syntax errors:

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE TRIGGER TOP_CUSTOMERS
AFTER INSERT ON ORDERS
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE msg VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'HIGH VALUE CUSTOMER - SALES GREATER THAN $10K';
    IF (SALES > 10000) THEN
        SET CUSTOMERNOTES = msg;
    END IF;
END;
||
DELIMITER ;
```

***Edit:***

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE TRIGGER TOP_CUSTOMERS
BEFORE INSERT ON ORDERS
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE msg VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'HIGH VALUE CUSTOMER - SALES GREATER THAN $10K';
    IF (NEW.SALES > 10000) THEN
        SET NEW.CUSTOMERNOTES = msg;
    END IF;
END;
||
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I only received 1 syntax error message, not multiple.  I have basic SQL data mining experience, but this is my first time delving into triggers.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: PLEASE, explain the use of DELIMITER ||.  This should be a very simple trigger, if after inserting data, if SALES > $10,000 set the CUSTOMERNOTES = 'HIGH VALUE CUSTOMER - SALES GREATER THAN $10K'.  CUSTOMERNOTES is a field in the ORDERS table, it's not a system variable...and I keep getting an "Undeclared system variable 'CUSTOMERNOTES' error message.

Comment: I tried running the suggested code above, and received a different Error Code: 1193.

Comment: About demiliter, read official doc; about logic, check the ***edit*** part. @MattMitchell

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out...here's what worked for me:

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE TRIGGER TOP_CUSTOMERS
AFTER INSERT ON ORDERS
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE CUSTOMERNOTES VARCHAR(100);
    IF (SALES > 10000) THEN
        SET CUSTOMERNOTES = 'HIGH VALUE CUSTOMER - SALES GREATER THAN $10K';
    END IF;
END;
||
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks everyone that responded for pointing me in the right direction.